# Define a record type in PL/SQL block that references a collection of itself

Tags: oracle, plsql, forward-declaration, hoisting

How to define a record type in PL/SQL anonymous block that contains a property that is a collection of itself? Look at the following example:

```
DECLARE
    type t_item is record (
        name varchar2(64),
        children t_items              -- referencing t_items type
    );
    type t_items is table of t_item;  -- referencing t_item type

BEGIN
    -- script code
END
```

PL/SQL has no type hoisting so Oracle engine raises an exception:

> PLS-00498: illegal use of a type before its declaration

How to define a record `t_item` that contains a `table of t_item` in its property `children`?

Comment: If you think in terms of rdbms, you want a table inside a table ? Doesn't seem very reasonable.

Comment: @SudiptaMondal There are no tables in the OP's question - this is about forward declaration of recursive PL/SQL data types.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use objects defined in the SQL Scope using inheritance:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a6aac/2)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TYPE abstract_item IS OBJECT (
  name VARCHAR2(64)
) NOT FINAL NOT INSTANTIABLE
/

CREATE TYPE t_items IS TABLE OF abstract_item
/

CREATE TYPE t_item UNDER abstract_item (
  children t_items
) INSTANTIABLE
/
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT t_item(
         '1',
         t_items(
           t_item( '1.1', t_items() ),
           t_item(
             '1.2',
             t_items(
               t_item( '1.2.1', null )
             )
           ),
           t_item( '1.3', null )
         )
       )
FROM   DUAL
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a6aac/2/1)**: (SQLFiddle doesn't display it nicely - but it runs without errors)

```
| T_ITEM('1',T_ITEMS(T_ITEM('1.1',T_ITEMS()),T_ITEM('1.2',T_ITEMS(T_ITEM('1.2.1',NULL))),T_ITEM('1.3',NULL))) |
|-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|                                                                                  oracle.sql.STRUCT@2a094aab |
```

You could use a similar declaration in PL/SQL:

```
DECLARE
  items t_item;
BEGIN
  items = t_item( 'Item Name', t_items( /* ... */ ) );
END;
/
```

Comment: It works, but how did you manage to get the results in an inner children, 1.2.1 in the example above?
I can get the values in items.children(<x>).name, but going deeper is giving me errors. I tried "dbms_output.put_line( items.children(2).children(1).name)" but I'm getting an error "PLS-00302: component 'CHILDREN' must be declared".

Comment: @Giliam `children` is a collection of `abstract_item` and not a collection of `t_item`. If you want to convert the abstract super-type to a concrete sub-type then use the `TREAT` function. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=a0d72f9fdd10d4b3db08ab540f85130f)

Comment: Thanks! That clarifies a lot.

Answer (score 2):

An example with reference to objects:

```
create or replace type item; -- forward declaration 
/
create or replace type l_item_ref is table of ref item;
/
create or replace type item  is object( a number, list l_item_ref)
/
CREATE TABLE t_item OF item nested table list store as ref_items
/
declare 

  v_list l_item_ref;

begin 

insert into t_item values(1,null);
insert into t_item values(2,null);
insert into t_item values(3,null);
select ref(p) bulk collect into v_list  from t_item p;

insert into t_item values(123,v_list);
 commit;
end;

select p.a,p.list from t_item p;
```

Comment: Is this limited to only being able to hold children that exist in a table? For example, is it possible to `insert into t_item values(4,l_item_ref( /* some reference to item( 5, null ) that is not stored in the table */ ));`

Comment: Yes it's limited only to stored objects.

Answer (score 0):

Below is an example of create a custom record type and then create table type using the custom record type.

In your spec file you can define the custom type as below.

```
TYPE STUDENT IS RECORD
    ("ID" NUMBER, 
     "NAME" VARCHAR2(100)
    );
TYPE STUDENT_TABLE IS TABLE OF STUDENT;
```

Now in your package body you can use the custom table which you have defined as below.

```
students STUDENT_TABLE; (Declaration of variable of type student_table)
```

As this does not work as a table you can not do direct insert on this. And one more thing to remember as in table if you insert record one after another it basically makes a new entry but in case of custom record type will replace the old one.

```
**SELECT
      123 AS ID,
      abc AS NAME
      BULK COLLECT INTO STUDENT_TABLE FROM DUAL;** --(This is how we insert)
```

Consider if we execute same statement with different values again it will override the previous one as explained above.

So if you have a requirement to append records then you can follow the below approach.

```
students STUDENT_TABLE;
studentsTemp STUDENT_TABLE; (Declare a temp also to store the previous value)

**SELECT
      123 AS ID,
      abc AS NAME
      BULK COLLECT INTO STUDENT_TABLE FROM DUAL;
studentsTemp := STUDENT_TABLE;

SELECT
    789 AS ID,
    xyz AS NAME
    BULK COLLECT INTO STUDENT_TABLE FROM DUAL;
studentsTemp := students multiset union all studentsTemp;** --(This is how you can append)
```

Below is the way to return it through cursor.

```
OPEN CursorStudent FOR
    SELECT ID,
           NAME,
      FROM TABLE(studentsTemp); (Will return all records.)
```

Advantage of using this is you can avoid temporary tables and less scripts to maintain when moving to higher environments.