# record linking to each other in PL/SQL Developer

Tags: oracle, plsql, record, user-defined-types

There was a need to create records in PL / SQL Developer, which refer to each other. I started to understand all this recently, therefore there were doubts about the achievement of this goal, but also the thought was spinning in my head that I was not the first to ask this question. Therefore, if you know how to do it or have ideas for implementation, I will be very glad of your help, but for now I will continue to google.

Example:

```
TYPE rtype1 IS RECORD
(
/*some code*/
r_type2 rtype2;
);

TYPE rtype2 IS RECORD
(
/*some code*/
r_type1 rtype1;
);
```

Additional Information:

The fact is that, on the basis of xsd schemes, you need to generate records and collections, but because In the xsd scheme this is not prohibited, such a need has arisen. And it is necessary to create types, and not to use the tools for working with xml.

Comment: 1. That is not possible; definitions must not be cyclical. 2. I doubt that "there was a need" for such a thing. Perhaps you could describe the problem you are trying to solve, rather than the flawed solution you are trying to develop?

Comment: You really need to explain what you are trying to achieve and why - including how you plan to populate and use these record types. You can pre-declare `rtype2` to allow `rtype1` to be declared; but you can't then have `rtype2` also refer back to `retype1`. Maybe you want objects instead of records so you can use refs, but you might actually want a completely different approach. Without understanding your goal properly we can't really advise on that though.

Comment: Pl/SQL Developer is a desktop IDE for working with Oracle databases. It’s not related to your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use forward declaration to declare the existence of a type in PL/SQL before you fully specify it. Like this:

```
DECLARE
  TYPE rtype2;                              -- Forward declaration
  TYPE rtype1 IS RECORD( r_type2 rtype2 );
  TYPE rtype2 IS RECORD( r_type1 INTEGER );
BEGIN
  NULL;
END;
/
```

However, you cannot use this to declare a non-REF mutually recursive type; if you try this:

```
DECLARE
  TYPE rtype2;
  TYPE rtype1 IS RECORD( r_type2 rtype2 );
  TYPE rtype2 IS RECORD( r_type1 rtype1 );
BEGIN
  NULL;
END;
/
```

Then you get the error:

```
ORA-06550: line 4, column 18:
PLS-00318: type "RTYPE2" is malformed because it is a non-REF mutually recursive type
ORA-06550: line 4, column 3:
PL/SQL: Item ignored
```

You can do it using object data types and a `REF` in the SQL scope:

```
CREATE TYPE otype1;                                       -- Forward declaration
CREATE TYPE otype2 IS OBJECT( o_type1 REF otype1 );
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE otype1 IS OBJECT( o_type2 otype2 );
```

But, again, if you try to use a non-REF mutually recursive type:

```
CREATE TYPE otype1;
CREATE TYPE otype2 IS OBJECT( o_type1 otype1 );
/* ORA-24344: success with compilation error */
CREATE TYPE otype1 IS OBJECT( o_type2 otype2 );
/* ORA-04055: Aborted: "OTYPE1" formed a non-REF mutually-dependent cycle with "OTYPE2". */
```

Then it doesn't work.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=812310479b9e0e0178bc25b40b49c2f5)*

Comment: I have one question. How i can use type with REF? I don't know how use variable type REF. And i find your [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52589579/define-a-record-type-in-pl-sql-block-that-references-a-collection-of-itself), how to access child variables from parent? Thank you in advance

Comment: @GodSon This is beyond the scope of your current question. If you want to ask them then ask a new question. However, don't ask for a tutorial as that is not what this site is about; instead attempt it yourself and then ask a question about the errors you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can define a type and then reference it in another type, which you define later in the code or on the system. However, as Alex asked, what are you trying to accomplish? -- Also contrary to what mathguy posted you can create and use types whose definitions are co-dependent.  I do not recommend doing so, but ...

[From the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/lnpls/CREATE-TYPE-statement.html#GUID-389D603D-FBD0-452A-8414-240BBBC57034):

> An **incomplete type** is a type created by a forward type definition. It is called incomplete because it has a name but no attributes or methods. It can be referenced by other types, allowing you define types that refer to each other. However, you must fully specify the type before you can use it to create a table or an object column or a column of a nested table type.

Comment: You are confusing object types (schema objects) and record types (PL/SQL). You can do what you say with objects, at least using refs; you can't with records, as they don't have a ref equivalent..

Comment: Your comments (and links) relating to cyclical definitions apply to SQL object types. Do they also apply to PL/SQL record types? (Perhaps they do, I wouldn't know, but what you posted isn't exactly answering the OP's question). Note also that the Oracle documentation - even for SQL objects - brushes over the distinction between data types and pointers to data types; the definitions are **not** cyclical.